# Manually install Emacs feature

Tags: emacs

I have a question about Emacs customisation.

For example, there is a git repo like https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile.

The directory structure is like:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 haoruan  staff    12K Nov  7 16:30 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--  1 haoruan  staff   1.5K Nov  7 16:30 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--  1 haoruan  staff   138B Nov  7 16:30 Cask
-rw-r--r--  1 haoruan  staff   884B Nov  7 16:30 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 haoruan  staff    28K Nov  7 16:30 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 haoruan  staff    39K Nov  7 16:30 helm-projectile.el
-rw-r--r--  1 haoruan  staff   4.4K Nov  7 16:30 persp-projectile.el
-rw-r--r--  1 haoruan  staff   112K Nov  7 16:30 projectile.el
drwxr-xr-x  7 haoruan  staff   238B Nov  7 16:30 screenshots
drwxr-xr-x  3 haoruan  staff   102B Nov  7 16:30 script
drwxr-xr-x  7 haoruan  staff   238B Nov  7 16:30 test
drwxr-xr-x  3 haoruan  staff   102B Nov  7 16:30 travis
```

It is suggested that the recommended way to install this feature is using MELPA. I can clone this git repo, but I can not ping MELPA. My question is how can I manually install this Emacs feature? More generic, how can I manually install such a Emacs feature which is using cask?

Comment: For most packages, it is usually sufficient to place the `*.el` files in the Emacs `load-path` and just `require` one or more of them in the `.emacs` or `init.el` file.  If you are interested in maximizing the speed at which Emacs starts, then there are certain advantages using `package.el` to install packages -- i.e., setting up certain stuff that is auto-loaded, and others that get loaded only when needed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your example,you dose not need cask

```
git clone https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile /some/place/you/want
```

Then add

`(add-to-load-path "/some/place/you/want")`

in your `.emacs` or `init.el`.Then

`(require 'projectile)`

manually.